# What kind of object is the Landau--Lifshitz pseudotensor?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I understand that it's called a pseudo-tensor because it's not a tensor. Wikipedia says

> most pseudo-tensors are sections of jet bundles, which are perfectly valid objects in GR.

Refer [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor)

Is the Landau-Lifshitz pseudo-tensor a section of a jet bundle?

Comment: the Landau-Lifshitz and Einstein pseudotensors are different objects, so you might want to edit your question to plural (or clarify in which one you're interested in)

Comment: @Christoph My bad. I saw the Landau--Lifshitz pseudotensor referred to as the Landau--Lifshitz--Einstein pseudotensor somewhere. Guess the source had a mistake.

Comment: Not directly on the topic of jet bundles, but Urs Schreiber has written a nice piece about fibre bundles and their use in physics http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+bundles+in+physics

Comment: I've also been looking for a reference to this statement

Answer (score 2):

Because the Landau-Lifshitz pseudotensor behaves as a tensor only with respect to restricted coordinate transformations, it would be considered as a part of the jet bundle within the manifold when used to this end only.

Comment: So like a jet bundle of order 2? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Very much like that!  I have no reference available however.